# VBA to save PDF from URL to local folder

Tags: vba, pdf, url, download

I'm trying to cycle through several url's to download the pdf to a local folder.

An example of the url is https://find-energy-certificate.service.gov.uk/energy-certificate/8309-9619-9729-7796-8423?print=true

This is the vb I've written so far.

```
Dim sveloc As String
Dim svenme As String
Dim url    As String

sveloc = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Saved EPCs"

i = 7
Do Until sh01.Cells(i, 27) = "" 'all cells in the list are populated with no gaps

    url = sh01.Cells(i, 27)
    svenme = sh01.Cells(i, 2)
    sveloc = sveloc & "\" & svenme & ".pdf"

        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (url)
        'code to open and save the pdf goes here

    i = i + 1

Loop
```

Any help gratefully received as I'm really stumped on this one.
TIA.

Comment: Your link is opening up save as PDF dialogue. Do you have proper link of pdf file?

Comment: unfortunately not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by KJ's answer, without error checking etc. Just wanted to illustrate how you'd use shell to automate the entire process.

```
sveloc = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Saved EPCs"

edgePath = Environ$("PROGRAMFILES(X86)") & "\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"

With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    i = 7
    Do Until Len(sh01.Cells(i, 27)) = 0 'all cells in the list are populated with no gaps
        On Error Resume Next
        .Run """" & edgePath & """ --profile-directory=Default --headless -print-to-pdf=""" & sveloc & "\" & sh01.Cells(i, 2) & ".pdf" & """ """ & sh01.Cells(i, 27) & """", 1, True
        On Error GoTo 0
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for VBA but you can use that to alter the variables so using your example from Windows we can run the **build pdf at html runtime** via Edge:-

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --profile-directory=Default --headless -print-to-pdf=C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\8309-9619-9729-7796-8423.pdf "https://find-energy-certificate.service.gov.uk/energy-certificate/8309-9619-9729-7796-8423?print=true"
```

and as if by magic the file is in less than a second on my desktop

[image]

There is no online pdf it is built by the browser. So it is essential to use the browser. You can remove the print header/footer with one extra switch, but cannot change orientation it will be A4 portrait in UK device.

`--no-pdf-header-footer` see current code as this newer.

one other switch may be of value if you only want smaller untagged files
`-disable-pdf-tagging`

If you try to download without browser printing you will just get the raw HTML as needed for web page printing, thus calling browser remote print as above, will generate the desired "designed for the web" graphics copy.

`curl -o test.htm https://find-energy-certificate.service.gov.uk/energy-certificate/8309-9619-9729-7796-8423?print=true`
[image]

In comments the question was raised how to adapt this approach for change of browser and keeping call simple so I suggest use a cmd or bat file to make that part easier. Thus from vba call something like

`Batchfile 8309-9619-9729-7796-8423`

```
@echo off
set "browser=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
set "filedir=C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop"
set "urlpath=https://find-energy-certificate.service.gov.uk/energy-certificate"

"%browser%" --profile-directory=Default --headless --print-to-pdf="%filedir%\%~1.pdf" --no-pdf-header-footer "%urlpath%/%~1?print=true"
```

However, beware calling pdf generations too fast, add a small wait between calls, even on multithreaded CPU writing PDF's at same time often leads to disasters, due to graphics resource conflicts.

Comment: Nice! OP could use the shell to repeat this for entire list on links.

Comment: Also, `Environ$("PROGRAMFILES(X86)") & "\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"` would probably give "safer" path to the ms edge

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try applying to my example and report back.

Comment: What would be the equivalent for Chrome?  I have Chrome as my default browser. I'm opening the url with FollowHyperlink. ` i = 7
    Do Until sh01.Cells(i, 27) = "" 'all cells in the list are populated with no gaps

        url = sh01.Cells(i, 27)
        svenme = sh01.Cells(i, 2)
        sveloc = sveloc & "\" & svenme & ".pdf"

            ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (url)
            
            'code to open and save the pdf goes here

        i = i + 1
'